# TS Generic type for class including null value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I receive data from API which is of type that depends on some other information OR equals *null* (API returns *null* if there is no value). I have created generic class (*Model*) and few classes that extend the *Model* (*Sample1*, *Sample2*...). How to define generic class that requires type 'something' OR *null*? I want to include null in type, because I use strict null checks and it would be helpful.

My requirements:

1. Generic class
2. Force type passed to generic to include null
3. Use strict null checks in all classes

```
type theType = null | {};

class Model<Base extends theType> {
    public value: Base = null;
    public sthElse: Base = null;
    public defaultValue: Base = null;
}

class IDontWantThisApproach<Base...
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMAWEBVzQLxQHYFcA22oB8oBvAXwG4AoCgY2wEMBnBqAWQHsATCbAHgCFG0CAA9gEdB2ZxEyAHzEKUJVDCYARtgCW1KADc62TBABcUAQ1QYc2SspXqtOhnACi2C6fOWsuW8tUa2lBcAGZ0OMAAagZGnoJQaD42FCRUtIzMAJIAImzowADqdPkIsJoMAIJgYABObHTUsPyC8kSK-g5B+oYmZvGESQlWvlAA9KNQIRDczDUQHJgSxcAwbFB0HBxQAOQD1tur67gq9NQQDO1KAY5QzrBuHn0We8eJ1n5XnTqh4dhRMb0vC88G9fCk0vQmFAAMp0AC2YGwQlE4kkrE43B4bTsmmAlS0ul6WDhaggNRSYwAVLdYGwcFsQmwamcYMhDqSoAAiJnDbCcqCUiatKipGiQ5iwhFIgBMUBEYgkzHYXF42OUuPxmkJpmcNU06AA5hTRtSGLT6ZMmSzQJB2dBuTVefzBbI1Z9AjpukYhm67FANRUCb1tgBNc7bS5QciR65BO4PbzvcFijIw+GIiAAZjlKMV6JVPF1+oNBF5rpjXz0AKGSQ+9g9t1c7ks2wQ52A20oovSUMlGYALDmFWjlZjfQGg6ZiaTySRS0l5JopRA4eI8fmx5GJ1qiZgSWSKcDhXZxjslxnV-kGAdGczzjB4KzbcA1vraJguLyADRQNSYFYcGw5zoNsAFrHCmCNDmZxgCst4PuUAB0UCZHB0zuFAcwLEs+SHNs8qoteRwMGw4JAA)

Answer (score 2):

Make it nullable !

```
type Nullable<T> = T | null;

class Model<Base extends theType> {
    public value: Nullable<Base>= null;
    public sthElse: Nullable<Base> = null;
    public defaultValue: Nullable<Base> = null;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBMAWEBVzQLxQHYFcA22oB8oBvAXwG4AoUSKAOR2wEMAjbCAHgQD4o0ECMDShQDGTAM7ioAWQD2AEwjZ2AIUbjoEAB7AI6eVLiJkPIhSgWoYTKwCWIqADdG2TBABcdBizar1ELjQsXEpLKxtseyhxOABRbA1PelwfDjUNHiChc0trOwdFADNGHGAANRc3JO9WNP9MwRCKEgpRCSkASQARWXRgAHVGPoRYW3EAQTAwACdZRhFYPwziHIs8yIdnVw8odOhCYLwskKgAelOoQoglKWmIeUx9IeAYWShGeXkoAHIDhm-Xu9cFYmCIIOJVuF8tE4gkdns-sDjthQrkIlEiiVsOVKvD-Iijo0Uc1WmJ1FIAMqMAC2YDYUG0un0UjkimUZjCtmAE0ijh2WGpzAg02aZwAVNFYLIcF9CrJpmCYMhAUKoAAieVEtVQMUXUytFptclQKm0tgAJgZOj0BhkCiU7A5li5PNsfM8MWmtnQAHNRacJeIpTLLvLFdRoMA3qqNdMtTrTlwnWt0ZtcbwVmFOdzxrydt8AJrg76Q8iQ9ZRGKweIaDOHSiGsmSE00ukQADMVqZttZDs93p9AkOSfLqac6eRqJT0KrNdQPwQ4OA3wbpPaLbNEAALF2bSz7ezIS7c27%20ZhBcLRQSeLZN9S9Ny7WzHUec3nPAKhSKSEOGPqwucPy3m2959OIAJygq4IwPASo0FGUDemImCKESAA0UDMJgLzyLI4LoN8OFvNSmALFaYJgC8kEwWMAB0UAdFR1wJFAdwPE8fSAt8jJ7gCLjiLIJJAA)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is basically the same as adding "| null" in all places. Isn't there a cleaner approach?